# From where or whom did Swami Vivekananda take sanyasa?

Tags: sanyasi, vivekananda, dashanami

Did he take up sanyasa under sankara mutt (dashanami sampradaya) or from some other source ?

If he took it from Ramakrishna then when did Sri Ramakrishna took sanyasa and what was his sanyasa name ?

Comment: It is well known that Swami Vivekananda was the disciple of Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa.

Comment: he received his sannyas from Ramakrishna Paramahamsa. Ramakrishna received his from Totapuri.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda but ramakrishna use to live with his wife and wear sacred thread. how come its allowed in sankara tradition? Did ramakrishna officially take sanyasa? what was his sanyasa name ?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Who did Totapuri receive Sanyasa from?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda As tota puri name indicates he was from Dashanaami which is evident from his suffix "puri". then the lineage should also follow dashanami rules and regulations . not just take sanyasa for namesake ...

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Totapuri or Tota Puri was a wandering monk who wore no clothes and never went inside buildings. He and his time with Ramakrishna are in the biography of Ramakrishna titled "The Great Master". There are even today scattered mentions of Totapuri throughout India. I came across a mention of his name near Nagpur some years ago. I vaguely remember that it said something like 'the sadhu known as Totapuri visited here'. Another monk told me that there are several mentions of him in central India. Quite remarkable for a wandering monk after almost 150 years.

Comment: 'Ramakrishna' was the name that He was known by. That was not his birth name. Ramakrishna took his sannyas vows and never consumated his marriage. When his wife came to Him after attaining a certain age, Ramakrishna told her she had the right to claim her marriage rights. She declined and lived separately in a small space under the nahabat. The space is so small that you cannot stand up in it.

Comment: The rules of sannyas are for vows against lust and greed. Ramakrishna could not touch any woman or money. He never owned anything, never touched money, never allowed money to be given to another person in his name. Perfect continence throughout his whole life. He wore the sacred thread before his sannyas. After he did not.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda when did he actually take up sanyasa? is it mentioned in his gospels ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi It is in "Vivekananda: A Biography" by Swami Nikhilananda

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda i m asking about Ramakrishna taking up sanyasa

Comment: Ramakrishna's sannyas is described in his biography called "Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master" (Part 2 Chapter XV) by Swami Saradananda

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda ji, did really sree ramkrishna took sanyas from Totapuri? I heard he only taught him Vedanta. Sree ramkrishna did tantra sadhona under the guidance of Vairabi maa.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath He had other teachers, but for learning advaita and sannyas it was Totapuri. I gave the chapter reference from his biography (above your comment) about Ramakrishna Paramahamsa taking sannyas from Totapuri.